# Python - Iterate through array with datetimes grouped by date

Tags: python, arrays, loops, datetime

I have a 2d array with one **ordered** column containing datetimes:

```
01/01/2000 06:30:00, string, string
01/01/2000 08:30:00, string, string
01/01/2000 10:30:00, string, string
...
02/01/2000 06:30:00, string, string
02/01/2000 08:30:00, string, string
02/01/2000 10:30:00, string, string
```

As I iterate through the array I don't want to perform operations on each element but instead I would like it to group them into rounded dates, work on that as a subset and then move on to the next group for the next date.

It feels a bit janky but would I need to go row by row, collect them into a temp array, work, flush, then move on? Or is there a facility in Python for a more elegant iterator that works with dates and times in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to make them into lists.

I have this sample list of **ordered** data with datetime as the first element, I hope I got what you meant:

```
old = [[datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 3, 0), 'test'], 
       [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 6, 0), 'test'], 
       [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 9, 0), 'test'], 
       [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 2, 9, 0), 'test'], 
       [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 2, 12, 0), 'test'], 
       [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 3, 2, 0), 'test'], 
       [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 3, 8, 0), 'test']]
```

You can use a lambda function to do operations and compare/group by the date/times. For example now I group by date only.

```
from itertools import groupby
new = []
for key, group in groupby(old, lambda x: x[0].date()):
    new.append(list(group))
```

The result is a list of lists group by dates.

```
[[[datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 3, 0), 'test'],
  [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 6, 0), 'test'],
  [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 9, 0), 'test']],
 [[datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 2, 9, 0), 'test'],
  [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 2, 12, 0), 'test']],
 [[datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 3, 2, 0), 'test'],
  [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 3, 8, 0), 'test']]]
```